# Notification: Sony devices do not show any notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, sony

I use these lines of code for showing notification in my app but sony devices(xperia p, sola, acro s) does not show any notification. I dont have any problem with other android devices.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityShowQuestion.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            Integer.parseInt(id), notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("text");
    Notification n = builder.build();

    nm.notify(id, n);
```

I googled for it but could not found any answer.

Comment: i have the 1st experia and im getting notifications with the code im using, its a little different, want me to post

Comment: yes thank you if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my onRecieve from a Broadcast, it makes notifications on xperia, i havent had any device problems with it you can chop it up if it works for you

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        Boolean entering = arg1.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
        String here = arg1.getExtras().getString("alert");
        String happy = arg1.getExtras().getString("type");



         NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(arg0, 0, arg1, 0);        

                Notification notification = createNotification();

                notification.setLatestEventInfo(arg0, 
                    "Entering Proximity!", "You are approaching a " + here + " marker.", pendingIntent);

                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


            }

            private Notification createNotification() {
                Notification notification = new Notification();

                notification.icon = R.drawable.icon;
                notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
                notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
                notification.ledOffMS = 1500;


                return notification;
            }
        //make actions



}
```

it doesnt use Builder idk exactly what is causing your problem, i know this works on xperia though

Comment: Thank you, I'm testing your code but one question , do you test this code on android 2.2? And one other thing is the setLatestEventInfo() method is deprecated.

Comment: yes the minsdk i have set is 8 and the setLatestEventInfo() says its depreciated, i have it on the market right now, it should still work depreciated methods still work right?

Comment: im really not sure, if you find out, post it up please, id like to keep up myself, and thank you