# Can't get a notification to show

Tags: android, android-notifications

Can't get the status bar notifications to work... I followed [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) guide, and created the following code in an `AsyncTask`, it's called from the `doInBackground()` method:

```
private void newNotification(int count) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(handler.getContext());
    builder.setContentTitle("New Notification");
    builder.setContentText("Testing notification");
    builder.setNumber(count);

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent intent = new Intent(handler.getContext(), MainActivity.class);

    // The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
    // started Activity.
    // This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
    // your application to the Home screen.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(handler.getContext());

    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) handler.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

`handler` is a reference to `MainActivity`, using an interface that implements `getContext()`, which returns `this.getContext()` of the `MainActivity`

For some reason when I call it with the parameter 1, nothing happens.

```
@Override
protected String[] doInBackground(String... empty) {
    newNotification(1);
    return null;
}
```

Debug shows that all the lines of the code are running, but no notifications appear. I didn't find any mention of a special permission, or that it needs to run from a UI thread anywhere. I assume it doesn't since background services are meant to notify... like when a message arrives.

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: look at this, this guy said it was using builder in his certain device, im into this question myself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314964/notification-sony-devices-do-not-show-any-notification/16315199#16315199

Comment: hmmm.. well I'm using Nexus 4 not Xperia, and I'd expect at least stock android to work fine... The builder is part of the official google SDK after all. Let's see if someone else knows something, I prefer to use the builder than create my own notification.

Comment: try onPostExecute() or onProgressUpdate() of AsyncTask, maybe the notification has to be done with the UIthread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Have you tried posting from the UI thread?

2) This is because services by default run in the UI thread unless explicitly put in a seprate thread.

3) Why don't you try a simple example first, like:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(handler.getContext());
builder.setContentTitle("New Notification");
builder.setContentText("Testing notification"); builder.setNumber(count);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), "hello", "hello", contentIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: I tried the UI thread, didn't change anything. There's no mention in any documentation that notifications are only available from the UI thread.

Comment: Your code didn't work either. not from UI or background thread.

Comment: Make the following changes

int icon = R.drawable.XXXX; (where xxxx is an icon in your drawable)
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "hello", when);

Set HELLO_ID as some integer, I have it as 2

Comment: This works. Apparently you must have an icon. My code also works when I add this line: `builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);`. Please edit your answer to use my code since I wanted to use the builder and not create my own notification, and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use notifications in my task to download a file, view its status and finally offer an notification to open the file with an pdf viewer. It might be helpful for you.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{
int                   NOTIFICATION_ID       = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
NotificationManager   notificationManager;
Notification          notification;

public MyTask() {

}

protected void onPreExecute()
{
}

protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
{
   [...]
        // Set initial notification
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_export_statusbar, "Download of " + downloadSubject + "  started...",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
        notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(appContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.download_progress);
        final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0, new Intent(), 0);
        notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
        notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon, R.drawable.ic_action_export_statusbar);
        notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.status_text, "Download of " + downloadSubjectShort + " in progress...");
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, progress, false);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);          
    [...]
}

protected void onCancelled()
{
    // remove the notification
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String pdfPath)
{
    // remove the notification
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
    if (pdfPath != null)
    {
        // show final notification to open pdf
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_export_finished_statusbar, "Download of " + downloadSubject
                + " finished...", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent();
        notifyIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(pdfPath);
        notifyIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(appContext, "Download finished", "open downloaded file",
                PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0, notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID + 1, notification);
    } else
    {
        // show final notification to inform about failure
        notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_action_export_failed_statusbar, "Error in download",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(appContext, "Download failed", "Error",
                PendingIntent.getActivity(appContext, 0, new Intent(), android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID + 1, notification);
    }
}
```

}